# 'list' object has no attribute 'items' when iterating through csv rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to extract values from a CSV file to create a list of filename:value

I keep getting

```
for header, value in row.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

this is the csv file's structure:

```
filename,id,points,value
image163.jpeg,0,67,6541546.633
image206.jpeg,1,67,5873455.229
image206.jpeg,1,67,5793978.982
image207.jpeg,2,67,6978847.211
image265.jpeg,3,67,6443535.129
```

This is the code I'm running:

```
with open('faces.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    facesreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    print(facesreader)
    faces_list = {}
    print(faces_list)
    for row in facesreader:
        print(row)
        for header, value in row.items():
            try:
                faces_list[header].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                faces_list[header] = [value]
```

Comment: `row` is a list, not a dictionary. You can't use `.items()`

Comment: Thanks, so I'm confused how should I iterate?

Comment: @TomBar-Gal, how do you want looks output ?

Comment: You use a `csv.reader`, but your code seems to be written for a `csv.DictReader`

Comment: I think best would be dictionary of filename:value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` should help you get the content as key-value pairs.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:
    facesreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in facesreader:
        print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
{'points': '67', 'id': '0', 'value': '6541546.633', 'filename': 'image163.jpeg'}
{'points': '67', 'id': '1', 'value': '5873455.229', 'filename': 'image206.jpeg'}
{'points': '67', 'id': '1', 'value': '5793978.982', 'filename': 'image206.jpeg'}
{'points': '67', 'id': '2', 'value': '6978847.211', 'filename': 'image207.jpeg'}
{'points': '67', 'id': '3', 'value': '6443535.129', 'filename': 'image265.jpeg'}
```